# What is the proper way to specify the port number for a VPN connection in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, vpn

I'm using Windows 7 Professional and I've setup an "office" connection (i.e. VPN connection), but I'm having trouble connecting to the VPN server. The port number I'm supposed to use is 3389, but I'm not sure if I'm specifying it correctly in the Host Name/IP Destination field, I tried the following:

```
alpha.domain.com:3389
```

In the Network and Sharing Center I choose the connection (e.g. Work VPN) and I provide my user name, password and domain, but I get an error:

```
Port opened.

Error 868: The remote connection was not made because the name of the remote access server did not resolve.
```

I am able to ping and tracert the domain: alpha.domain.com and everything looks good from that perspective.

One more thing to note is that I'm using an air card (Verizon Wireless) so the connection dialog shows:

```
Connecting to alpha.domain.com:3389 using 'WAN Miniport SSTP'...
```

Any ideas on why this may be happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What protocol is the VPN utilizing?  your connection is going through as SSTP which should by default use TCP port 443.  You are getting the name error because it is trying to resolve "alpha.domain.com:3389" and not "alpha.domain.com".

Comment: CHeekaleak, turns out I made a mistake... the port number they provided me with was for RTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Windows' built-in VPN setup will only work on port 1723 (PPTP) or 443 (SSTP). You can try a standalone client like [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) to connect to this VPN instead.

I do notice though that the VPN you are describing is using the remote desktop port. Are you sure it's a VPN, and not a terminal server? Try connecting to it with a remote desktop client (mstsc.exe).

Comment: You're right, that port number I was given was not valid... it was using the default port numbers for windows and all I needed to do is use the address provided.